# AIR Keyboard shortcut for a button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I work with AIR application.
In this application, several windows are displayed.

I like to close windows with shortcuts like <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I try to do that like this:

```
// On creation complete
this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, exit_keyDownHandler);

// exit function
protected function exit_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
 if  ((event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
    ||(event.keyCode == Keyboard.NUMPAD_ENTER)
    ||(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)){
       stage.nativeWindow.close();
    }
}
```

But if a text area exists on window, a problem occured. Because when user presses  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key text area window closes. How can that be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Closing with a single key other than the escape key doesn't seem like a very good idea to me, especially not with the enter key.

However, if you insist doing it like that, then you could try checking the current focused object to make sure it's not an input element/component that accepts the enter key.

See [FocusManager.getFocus(](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/FocusManager.html#getFocus%28%29)) and [Stage.focus](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#focus). A very restrictive check could for example look like this:

```
if(focusManager.getFocus() is IFocusManagerComponent ||
   stage.focus is InteractiveObject || stage.focus is IFocusManagerComponent)
{

}
```